# input.type = "number"; but only for specific input field

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

How I can use my : `input.type = "number";` to be used only in specific fields?

```
            var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
            var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
            var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
            var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
```

I have these inserts, to insert fields into the table. So how can I specify only for the eg. Cell(0)? To have only numbers (0-9) in the specific fields.

Sorry if sounds stupid.
Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor. Your code does not have any input fields

Comment: Cells in a row are content elements not inputs. Content elements have no number type. Are you wanting to insert inputs into those cells? This question is very unclear. Provide a more detailed explanation of what you are looking for

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you only create a **cell**. To add a input field you simply create one (as shown below) and append it to your cell like this:

```
const input = document.createElement('input');
      input.setAttribute('type', 'number'); 
      input.setAttribute('min', 0); 
      input.setAttribute('max', 9); 

cell1.appendChild(input)
```

Some resources for you to learn about all this:

- https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_min.asp
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement

I hope this helps ;)

Comment: `function AddRow(TableName) {
        var table = document.getElementById(TableName);
        var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
        var row = table.insertRow(rows.length);

        if (TableName == 'Table1') {
            var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
            var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
            var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
            var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);

            cell1.innerHTML = ' '; `

Comment: If you want to paste the element via innerHTML you can go like this `cell1.innerHTML = `<input type="number" min="0" max="0">`. If this solved your problem please mark it as answered so others can find it too.